# Fuchsia OS fxl::CommandLineFromArgcArgv() usage?

Tags: fuchsia

[Fuchsia OS > Guides > Syslog](https://fuchsia.dev/fuchsia-src/development/languages/c-cpp/syslog) has this example:

```
#include "src/lib/fsl/syslogger/init.h"
#include "src/lib/fxl/command_line.h"
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    auto command_line = fxl::CommandLineFromArgcArgv(argc, argv);
    fsl::InitLoggerFromCommandLine(command_line, {"my_program"});
}
```

[Fuchsia OS > Reference](https://fuchsia.dev/reference) does not have FXL listed:

[image]

A search of the [Fuchsia Project site](http://Fuchsia%20Project%20site) has one additional example that has `fxl::CommandLineFromArgcArgv()`.

Where do I find arguments, return value and other details on `fxl::CommandLineFromArgcArgv()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fxl` API is not documented as part of the official Fuchsia reference (yet).

From the readme in the `fxl` directory ([link](https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/fuchsia/+/master/src/lib/fxl#should-i-put-my-thing-in-fxl)):

> In an ideal world, FXL wouldn‘t exist and we could use the C++ standard library’s building blocks. [...] We‘d like to keep FXL small and focused on the problem of “fixing” the C++ standard library, which means you probably shouldn’t put your thing in FXL unless it is related to a particular deficiency of the C++ standard library.

Based on this statement, it seems `fxl` is not set up as a long-term project, but rather is meant to become empty/obsolete, when the C++ standard library has been sufficiently adapted. It is possible that documentation effort has been limited for this reason.

We have to rely on the documentation provided directly in the header ([link](https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/fuchsia/+/master/src/lib/fxl/command_line.h)):

```
// Builds a |CommandLine| from the usual argc/argv.
inline CommandLine CommandLineFromArgcArgv(int argc, const char* const* argv)
```

The `CommandLine` class is defined in the same header. According to the comments, it distinguishes between optional and positional args. Optional arguments are of the form `--key=value` or `--key` (with no value), but not `--key value`. The positional arguments begin with the first argument not of this form (or the special `--` separator).

The `CommandLine` member functions are:

- Accessing the program name (from `argv[0]`):

  ```
  bool has_argv0() const;
  const std::string& argv0() const;
  ```
- Accessing the optional and positional arguments (`Option` being a simple struct with members `std::string name` / `std::string value`):

  ```
  const std::vector<Option>& options() const;
  const std::vector<std::string>& positional_args() const;
  ```
- Comparison:

  ```
  bool operator==(const CommandLine& other) const;
  bool operator!=(const CommandLine& other) const;
  ```
- Accessing optional arguments:

  ```
  bool HasOption(StringView name, size_t* index = nullptr) const;
  bool GetOptionValue(StringView name, std::string* value) const;
  std::vector<StringView> GetOptionValues(StringView name) const;
  std::string GetOptionValueWithDefault(StringView name, StringView default_value) const;
  ```

We can write the following example program (uses [structured-binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) syntax):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "src/lib/fxl/command_line.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  const auto cl = fxl::CommandLineFromArgcArgv(argc, argv);

  std::cout << "Program name = " << cl.argv0() << std::endl;

  std::cout << "Optional: " << cl.options().size() << std::endl;

  for (const auto& [name,value] : cl.options()) {
    std::cout << name << " -> " << value << std::endl;
  }

  std::cout << "Positional: " << cl.positional_args().size() << std::endl;

  for (const auto& arg : cl.positional_args()) {
    std::cout << arg << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

After compiling the program (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60859528/fuchsia-os-build-command-fx-set-with-produces-include-not-allowed) answer), we can get the following output (demonstrating how first positional argument `filename` turns all following arguments into positional arguments):

```
$ hello_world_cpp --k1=v1 --k2 --k3=v3 filename --k4=v4
Program name = hello_world_cpp
Optional: 3
k1 -> v1
k2 ->
k3 -> v3
Positional: 2
filename
--k4=v4
```

Demonstrating `--` as a separator:

```
$ hello_world_cpp --k1=v1 -- --k2=v2
Program name = hello_world_cpp
Optional: 1
k1=v1
Positional: 1
--k2=v2
```

We could do simple argument parsing using `HasOption`:

```
    size_t index;

    if (cl.HasOption("key", &index)) {
      handle_key(cl.options.at(index).value);
    }
```

Adding this to our program and calling it with `--key=abc` would then pass `abc` to `handle_key`.

Comment: Thanks, I will get back to looking at your answers. This is kind of a lonely landscape in Fuchsia land.