# Fuchsia OS build command: fx set --with, produces: Include not allowed

Tags: gn, fuchsia

[fuchsia/examples/intl/tz_version_parrot/main.cc](https://github.com/vsrinivas/fuchsia/blob/master/examples/intl/tz_version_parrot/main.cc) uses `fxl::CommandLineFromArgcArgv()`:

```
#include "src/lib/fxl/command_line.h"
...
int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
  const auto command_line = fxl::CommandLineFromArgcArgv(argc, argv);
```

[Fuchsia > Guides > fx workflows](https://fuchsia.dev/fuchsia-src/development/build/fx) show the use of `fx set --with`:

```
$ fx set workstation.x64 --with //bundles:tests
```

I modified the hello world example to use `fxl::CommandLineFromArgcArgv()`:

```
~/fuchsia$ cat examples/hello_world/cpp/hello_world.cc 
#include <iostream>
#include "src/lib/fxl/command_line.h"

int main(int argc_a, char** argv_a) {
    auto command_line = fxl::CommandLineFromArgcArgv(argc_a, argv_a);
    std::cout << "hello has_argv0():" << command_line.has_argv0() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
~/fuchsia$ fx set bringup.x64 --with //examples/hello_world
ERROR at //examples/hello_world/cpp/hello_world.cc:2:11: Include not allowed.
#include "src/lib/fxl/command_line.h"
          ^-------------------------
It is not in any dependency of                                                                                           
  //examples/hello_world/cpp:bin
The include file is in the target(s):
  //src/lib/fxl:fxl
which should somehow be reachable.
```

which produces errors. The original works fine:

```
~/fuchsia$ cat examples/hello_world/cpp/hello_world.cc 
#include <iostream>
//#include "src/lib/fxl/command_line.h"

int main(int argc_a, char** argv_a) {
//    auto command_line = fxl::CommandLineFromArgcArgv(argc_a, argv_a);
//    std::cout << "hello has_argv0():" << command_line.has_argv0() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
~/fuchsia$ fx set bringup.x64 --with //examples/hello_world
Generating JSON projects took 3090ms
Generating compile_commands took 219ms
Done. Made 26946 targets from 2635 files in 16354ms
```

What is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `./examples/hello_world/cpp/BUILD.gn`, extend the `hello_world_cpp` module declaration with the `fxl` dependency:

```
executable("bin") {
  output_name = "hello_world_cpp"

  sources = [ "hello_world.cc" ]

  deps = [ "//src/lib/fxl" ] # Add this line
}
```

```
cd fuchsia
fx set bringup.x64 --with //examples/hello_world
fx build; fx qemu
...
hello_world_cpp
hello has_argv0():1
```

Reference: The same is done in other Fuchsia components that use `fxl` ([link](https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/fuchsia/+/e926a9f38ccea28c8c6d8525b2836a5f2ba72d8e/src/lib/json_parser/BUILD.gn#42)).